# What do I do if I have a ViewFlipper and ScrollView only wraps one child?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollviewer, viewflipper

I really only need my `ScrollView` wrapped around 1 of the 3 `LinearLayout`s I have in my `ViewFlipper`, but I try to wrap it around my 3rd child and it gives me the error that `ScrollView` can only host one direct child.

Any workarounds?

```
<ViewFlipper>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="110dp">

      <!--- Stuff --->

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - make the one child of your `ScrollView` a `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and put the content in that.

Comment: I placed the code around the linear layout like above and it still gave me that error.  I have 3 child linear layouts in my ViewFlipper -does that mean I cannot have a scroll view?

Comment: Of course you can, but you need to have *one* child for the scrollview, and not 3. If you want 3 views in your ViewFlipper, you could put each in its own ScrollView, but... can I ask why you're trying to put a ScrollView inside a ViewFlipper with 3 children instead of putting your ViewFlipper inside the ScrollView? Also, please show the <!--Stuff--> -- you snipped the only important part of your layout because whatever's in there is what's actually causing the error.